# Remove color and redirect ouptut of a bash script from within

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr

My question is simple, how can I redirect all outputs of a bash script to **file and terminal** and **remove color** characters **from within** the script itself?

I can't find an answer which fits all my needs.

So far I tried `tee` to output to file and terminal, combined with `2>&1` to get `stederr` and `stdout`, `sed` to remove color characters and all of this with `exec` to do it from within my script but it doesn't work, I only get colored logs into the terminal and nothing in file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec 2>&1 | sed -r 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g' | tee script.logs

python somepython.py
python someotherpython.py
```

Here the python scripts produce outputs which are colored.

I want to log those to terminal (untouched) and in file (without the color). In reality there is a lot more going on in my bash script than those just two python scripts, that's why I want to globally redirect the output of my script bash and not just pipe after each python script.

Thus I used `exec` because I though it allowed to redirect all output produce by a script.

Thanks in advance for any advice and help,

PS: I dont want colored logs in file but I don't care in terminal if this is what needs to be done for logs to not be colored in file.

Comment: Color is only a representation your terminal does of the bytes it receives. There is no *color* in a file, only bytes.

Comment: @MatiasBarrios they do appear as ANSI escape code in my file like so `\033[33m` though

Comment: AFAIK, `exec 2>&1 | ...` isn't a meaningful operation in bash -- the `exec` is scoped to the single pipeline element it takes place in. Someone might *expect* it to behave identically to `exec 2>&1 > >(sed -r 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g' | tee script.logs)`, but it isn't (unless that's a very recent -- say, bash 5.x -- change I'm unaware of).

Comment: @VictorGalisson, if your program is writing ANSI escape codes to a non-terminal output, that's bad behavior that should be fixed. Well-behaved programs check if `isatty()` is true before writing terminal control sequences to stdout (and also don't assume an ANSI-compatible terminal, but use a library like curses that can map the current `TERM` environment variable to the right color codes for that specific terminal).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may put all your calls in a curly-braced group and redirect the whole lot, e.g.:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
{
  python somepython.py
  python someotherpython.py
} 2>&1 | sed -r 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g' | tee script.logs
```

This way, all stdout and stderr outputs will be passed along the filter.

### Color the terminal, not the file

If you want to write the colors to the terminal and write the uncolored text to the file, you may apply the `sed` filter to the file written by `tee`, e.g. your script would look something like:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
{
  python somepython.py
  python someotherpython.py
} 2>&1 | tee >(sed -r 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g' > script.logs)
```

This uses [process substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) which is a very powerful tool in bash, albeit a bit difficult at first.

### Remove buffering

Assuming you would like to read the contents as soon as possible, you may want to deactivate python’s block buffering. This can be done using the [`-u`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u) option:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
{
  python -u somepython.py
  python -u someotherpython.py
} 2>&1 | tee >(sed -r 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g' > script.logs)
```

### Side Note: Beware of CSI

Not all special characters are based on the Control Sequence Initiator `ESC [`.

If a text is colored in green with `tput setaf 1`, it will use the control sequence `ESC [31m`, but if the color is reset with `tput sgr0`, the control sequence may be `ESC (B ESC [m` (please note the `ESC (B` sequence). So if you filter only the `ESC [` sequences, you may still have control sequence waste in your log file.

Things get even worse if the program uses other types of control characters such as cursor commands.

For those reasons, the best way to avoid problems is to simply avoid writing control sequences from your python scripts. Most builtin programs are protected against that by checking if the output is a terminal before choosing to display colors or not. When the output is not a terminal it assumes that colors may cause issues.

With that said I don’t know if you have control over the python scripts (or other calls you might have), but if you do you might want to test if the output is a terminal. In Bash you check this way:

```sh
if [ -t 1 ] # does stdout end up on a terminal?
then
  # Display fancy colors
else
  # Minimalist display
fi
```

In Python it would be:

```py
if sys.stdout.isatty(): # does stdout end up on a terminal?
  # Display fancy colors
else:
  # Minimalist display
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the "display color only if stdout is a terminal" approach you're suggesting here is pretty much standardized -- it's what `ls --color=auto` and many other common tools do, and thus a behavior users should generally not be surprised by.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you are right and I wanted to add that, for example, some linux distros will `alias ls='ls --color=auto'` but I did not want to provide too many details because this section was already drifting beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: thanks for your explanation ! I'm very new to bash and I didn't really know how `exec 2>&1` works. Sorry for my mistake, I don't redirect a program to my script but I was just trying to get both `stdout` and `stderr `in file.What I'm trying to do is redirect output the script does to file and terminal from within.

Comment: @VictorGalisson ok but your text has to become from somewhere. Your example just shows how you want to filter, but it does not show what feeds this filter. Can you edit your question to show where is the program or script that writes the colored text?

Comment: @VictorGalisson Your question makes a lot more sense, thank you. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @vdavid ty for your reply, it works with a simple "hello world" script like so `{    
    echo "hello world"
} 2>&1 | sed -r 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g' | tee script.logs` but doesn't for my script. I'm scratching my head on why this occurs maybe something with some of my `if` statements or `exit 1`, thanks anyway

Comment: @VictorGalisson What do you mean by "doesn't work for my script"? It does not display anything? The colors are still part of the log file?

Comment: @vdavid it doesn't output anything in file nor terminal :/

Comment: @VictorGalisson What happens when you run this command line: `{ python -c 'print "\033[32mYOLO\033[m"'; } 2>&1 | tee >(sed -r 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g' > script.logs)` (no need to put it in a script, you can copy/paste it to the terminal)

Comment: @vdavid it correctly prints YOLO in green to terminal and without ANSI escape code in file. It is really weird that I don't have the same behavior for my script.

Comment: That’s weird, indeed. Please note I made a mistake in my answer, i.e. my second code sample writes to `scripts.logs` instead of `script.logs`.

Comment: @VictorGalisson You could also try to use the `-u` option to force python to print as soon as possible without buffering, e.g. `python -u somepython.py`

Comment: @vdavid okay so I found out that the script does work but everything is written to terminal and file only once the script is finished (with `-u` or not). Which loose the point of writing to a terminal alongside a file.